# ListBox.SelectedItem refuses to be set

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, selecteditem

What are the likely causes of the exception being thrown in the following code?

```
var oldItem = this.MyListBox.SelectedItem;

if (this.MyListBox.Items.Contains(newItem))
{
    this.MyListBox.SelectedItem = newItem;

    if (this.MyListBox.SelectedItem != newItem && this.MyListBox.SelectedItem == oldItem) 
        throw new ApplicationException("WTF?");
}
```

At no point is the ListBox.SelectionChanged event raised.

EDIT: oldItem and newItem are simple business objects of the same type. They are not null.

Comment: @Matt What is your newItem - how you initiate it?

Comment: Where is this being performed?

Comment: Multithreading is the most obvious guess - other thread modifies selected item while your thread goes through conditions

Comment: You ask on what situations could your code throw that exception, is that correct? My first guess is: You have a filter view on your collection, and you try to set the selected item to an object that is removed while filtering.

Comment: This is in the code behind of a UserControl. dowhilefor I think you might have the correct answer here. I will investigate further.

Comment: Have you used a breakpoint to see what is the value of newItem when you set it as selecteditem ? Have you used a breakpoint to see what happens after that line ?

Comment: Are oldItem and newItem valid values that aren't null?  It's tough to diagnose with the limited information provided.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either use the [SetSelected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.setselected.aspx) method like so:

```
MyListBox.SetSelected(index, true);
```

or set it on the item itself like so:

```
MyListBox.Items(index).Selected = true;
```

I'm not sure what `newItem` is in your question, so you will need to identify it's index in the list and put that in where I have `index` in the above snippets.